# Orthonormal bases: Does a complex vector 3-space have twice as many bases as a real vector 3-space?

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-spaces

Apologies in advance if the title sounds weird. Anyway,

I'm brushing up on my math, reading "Modern Mathematical Analysis."  Early on it discussed vector spaces, mainly 3-space, and it wasn't difficult: the basis **e**$_1$ is the vector from 0 to 1 on the x-axis, etc.

Now it is extending to complex spaces, but it still talks in terms of **e**$_i$ without breaking it down into real and complex. So my guess is: **e**$_1$ is the vector from 0 to 1 on the real x-axis, **e**$_2$ is the vector from 0 to 1$\cdot$*i* on the imaginary x-axis, and so forth (so four more). Is that correct? 
Also, regarding the title: is the complex analog of real 3-space still called 3-space? Or must it be called 6-space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the dimension of a vector space is just the number of basis vectors it has. So a 3 dimensional complex vector space has exactly 3 basis elements for any basis. In particular any basis of $\mathbb{C}^3$ has 3 elements. It is true that there is a sense in which $\mathbb{C}^3$ is related to $\mathbb{R}^6$ but that does not make it 6 dimensional as a vector space.  However, your intuition might tell you that its geometry is 6 dimensional. However, importantly that isn't a vector space quality.

For a concrete example, let's look at the 1 dimensional vector space of $\mathbb{C}$ over itself. This is indeed 1 dimensional, not 2 dimensional, so then {1, $i$} should not be a basis of this. and indeed it isn't, because 1 and i are not linearly independent, as $1=i\cdot(-i)$

However, it should be noted if its a complex vector space, then we are looking at it as a vector space over the field $\mathbb{C}$, we can also consider $\mathbb{C}$ or even $\mathbb{C}^3$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ in which case, the first one is 2 dimensional, and the second is 6 dimensional.

Comment: Thanks. My confusion stems from the simple planar graphs (reals on the horizontal, imaginary on the vertical) which look 2-d. But from what you say, that would have a basis of {1}, i.e. a 1-d basis which can be multiplied by a real or an imaginary.

Comment: If you think my answer, answers your question you should mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: Done, sorry for the delay, still learning.